# Fitting a linear model with few extreme values

Tags: r, linear-algebra, regression

I want to estimate a parameter (let's call it x) by some other paramaters via some linear model. Usually I take lm() in R for such purposes.

However, in my situation the parameter x is mostly very close to 0 and just for a handful exceptions (which amount to 1-2% of the total number of samples) or do see values whose absolute values does deviate significantly from 0.
So when I apply lm() in R when using 10-fold CV, I correctly predict, of course, most parameter values to be 0, but the 1-2% outliers are not captured appropriately, meaning that the predictions are much to mild for the heavy outliers, so, for instance, if the actual value is +0.5 the predicted value is +0.2 or so.

My question is now how to create a linear model (in R), which predicts the close to 0 values correctly (but a little more trade-off should be allowed here), but which recaptures the deviances of the outliers much more accurately.

Comment: @Carlise Actually the outliers are precisely the ones I am interested in, so I want to create a model that works particularly well on the outliers, but still correclty predicts the other values to be close to 0.

Comment: Given your interest in the outliers, a linear model may not appropriately describe the error structure in your data.

Comment: Agreed with vpipkt:  you can't simultaneously force a linear fit and include "outliers" which are not linear in nature.

Comment: @vpipkt and  Carl Witthoft: Well my aim is precisely to include the outliers and to have a linear model that recaptures their behvaior well, but at the same time is not too bad wrt to the samples that are barely != 0.

Comment: Perhaps your data have an underlying structure causing some observations to behave one way, and some to behave another. For one subset, you are clearly happy with a linear model. For the other subset a different technique may be necessary. Can you think of what may be driving the outlier behavior?

Comment: Well I happen to have some other data where the data points are not so tightly clustered around 0 (with the exception of the outliers). Then I can predict everything, also those heavily changing data points quite well. Hence, I believe that there is a good linear model for it, but the fitting method is probably bad.

Comment: It is difficult to determine just what you mean by "parameter." Does this refer to one of the unknown coefficient you are fitting (which is the standard meaning), to something you are trying to predict, or something else?